# How to achieve formView and ListView on one page [DJANGO 1.8]

Tags: django

I am trying to create a page with the following layout:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------
|  |----------------------------------|
|  |  See details: Owner (dropdown)   | -> Form
|  |----------------------------------|
|
|  |----------------------------------|
|  |  Computer brand: DELL            | -> List of computers
|  |  member_field1                   |
|  |  member_field2                   |
|  |  ------------------------------- |
|  |  Computer brand: ASUS         v  |  -> first computer should have
|  |  ------------------------------- |     all of his details visible
|  |  Computer brand: TAMAGOCHI    v  |     while the next ones should 
|  |                                  |     be collapsed
```

My functionality is when the user selects a Owner from the dropdown to be redirected to /Owner/ID/ and to have the details of all computers associated with him displayed bellow.

I would also like to have a default "create new Owner" field in the dropdown as the first possible choice and see below a create Owner form.

I have been struggling for hours with this trying to understand all of the Views, generic Views and things.

Things that I have (those are not real examples so the code is not even compiled but it shows the general things I have in my app right now):

```
# models
class Computer(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    member_field1
    member_field2
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Owner')

class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

# forms
class OwnerForm(forms.Form):
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(querySet=Owner.objects.all())

# views
class ComputerOwnerDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Computer
    template_name = 'computer_owner_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super.get_context_data
        context['owner_chooser_form'] = OwnerForm(initial = {'field1':context['object'].id})
        context['owned_computers_list'] = Computer.objects.all()[:10]
        return context

# urls
url(r'^owner/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ComputerOwnerDetailView.as_view(), name='owner_detail'),

# template
{% extends 'android/index.html' %}
{% block where_it_has_to_go_in_base %}

<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ owner_chooser_form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button
</form>

{% if computer_owner_detail %}
<ul>
  {% for computer in computer_owner_detail %}
  <li>{{ computer.brand }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
 <p> No computer Defined Yet </p>
{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

There are several problems (questions) I have with this.

1. OwnerForm(initial = {'field1':context['object'].id}) => does not preselect the owner
2. context['owned_computers_list'] = Computer.objects.all()[:10] => this gets all the computers - I want to filter them by owner but have no access to the owner in this method

I am pretty sure my whole architecture is wrong. I shouldn't be using a DetailsView since I am not really presenting any details for the model I have attached the view to ( ComputerOwnerDetailView -> Computer ). But I do not know how to achieve the required functionality.

Right now when I submit the form it gets me back to the same URL but with a POST, however I can not handle POST ( or at least couldn't find a way ) in the current setup so that I can see the new ID of the Owner that the user has selected with the dropdown and redirect to owner/NEW_ID/ so that the computers associated this new owner are listed

Can you please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your view:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class ComputerOwnerDetailView(generic.FormView):

...

    def form_valid(self,form):
        owner = get_object_or_404(Owner,pk=form.cleaned_data['owner']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('owner_details',owner.id))
```

If you want a custom page instead of 404:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def form_valid(self,form):
    try:
        owner = Owner(pk=form.cleaned_data['owner']
        ulr = reverse('owner_details',owner.id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        url = reverse("another-view")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: This does not work. the 'form_valid' method never gets called

Comment: You are right, sorry, it should be a generic.FormView to trigger form_valid. But now you have to fetch the computer_owner_detail to the context and not rely on CBV: context['computer_owner_detail'] = ... (I wouldn't recommend messing with subclassing both DetailsView and FormView)

Comment: Hey I tried the new way but it still did not work. I am investigating other possibilities and will post if I find the working one.